# Need Final Re-Ordered data from jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, salesforce, apex

I have a Visualforce Page which shows some list of records in order. I have implemented jQuery DataTables to Re-order the row and want to save the final reordered data to server. I have written the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                rowReorder: {
                    selector: 'tr'
                },
                columnDefs: [
                    { targets: 1, visible: true }
                ]
            } );
            table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
               alert('chnaged');
                console.log(table.rows().data());
            } );

        } );
```

I am getting the initial data in the `console.log(table.rows().data());` I want the final reordered data. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier** ...Use

```js
console.log( table.rows({ order: 'current' }).data() )
```

instead.